# Enable packet routing from network interface eth0 to bridge interface

Tags: networking, server, iptables, routing, network-bridge

I have a Ubuntu server connect to LAN `10.1.200.21/24 (bond0)`, and an Macbook connect to LAN `10.1.200.50/24 (eno1)`

There are another bridge create by `brctl addbr br0` in Ubuntu `10.3.100.1/24`, and there are three VMs connect to that bridge.

[image: This picture show the entire network topology]

My question is how to access those VMs `10.3.100.x/24` from my Macbook `10.1.200.21`?

The routing table on Macbook

```
Destination   Gateway        Flags    Refs  Use       Netif
10.3.100/24   10.1.200.21    UGSc      0     4376     eno1
...
```

The routing table on Ubuntu

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.1.200.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0
10.3.100.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
...
```

I can ping those VMs from my Ubuntu server. However, when I try to ping VMs from Macbook, the packet only send to `bond0` on Ubuntu, but not routed to `br0` (tracked by tcpdump).

Besides, I have enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`.

Comment: Did you try to set the gateway in your last line to the local IP address of br0?

Comment: Sorry, I found the dug came from ceph(another storage system on my ubuntu). It somehow block the IO, after I clean that up and reboot, everything work well. Thanks you anyway :)